# How can I adjust my fitness routine to account for my insulin resistance?

Tags: weight-loss, health

For the past few months I have been trying to lose fat/build muscle/generally become more fit, but have not been seeing any progress. After a bit of googling, I found that insulin resistance, which I was diagnosed with years ago, can hinder attempts to lose fat. Are there methods I can use to try to account for this difficulty?

I already try to avoid carbs when I can - and when I do eat them I opt for whole grain - but are there things I can eat/exercises I can do that will make my attempts more fruitful?

In case it helps, my usual work out routine is minimum 2x week 30min weight training w/ 10 min cardio warm-up, + 30 minute elliptical as many times as I can fit into my schedule, and my average caloric intake is about 1500 mostly from meat, veggies + fruits. 22yo female 5'4 ~140-145lbs

Comment: Why did you decide on 1700 calories? Did you get that number from a tdee calculator? Possibly you need to lower your caloric intake

Comment: I use MyFitnessPal, and based on its suggestions that is my ideal goal if I want to lose ~.5lbs per week. I tend to actually eat around 1500-1600, though.

Comment: MFP routinely overestimated calories necessary by quite a bit. If your compare their results with many other online calculators you will see quite a difference. If you are not losing weight I suggest you take your calories down to 1400-1500

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just checked with a couple other calculators and they suggested 1600-1700.

Comment: What are you putting in for activity level? That's what usually makes the most difference

Comment: Lightly active, though I'm aiming for moderately active once my schedule frees up so I can work out more often.

Comment: Just a random calculator http://www.calorieking.com/interactive-tools/how-many-calories-should-you-eat/ sets you lightly active at 1700-1900 for maintaining not losing. These calculators are not individualized so if you are not losing you should drop your calories as long as it's in a safe range

Answer (score 1):

High intensity interval training and weight lifting are both very good protocols for insulin resistant people. 
Studies that point to weight lifting increasing insulin sensitivity 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20351587
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15628572
HIIT effect on insulin resistance study
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2640399/

You can search around as there are a lot more, i just quoted a few
As with all studies the only way to know if they are really true is to try them out (where there is no risk) and see for yourself

Comment: And why is that? :) Is there any authority or reasoning you can appeal to?

Comment: Is this opinion, or, based on factual evidence?

Comment: There are numerous studies that show this . Again these are just studies, not facts set in stone. I will edit my response to reflect the sources